# The scheme of Android Studio displays color wrong

Tags: android-studio, themes

The code, that I typed, displays color completely different from the sample code. And I have no idea how to make it displays as the sample one. This bug appears on every scheme, including Default one.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the 'Power save mode' is turned on. We just have access to menu `File > Power Save Mode` to turn it off then code scheme will be displayed as normal.